# working with XSLT own function on inputed XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

*XML:*

```
<root> 
  <event title="Title1" />
  <event title="Title2" />
</root>
```

*C#*

```
public static string **retunxml**(){
    XmlNode xmln_list = [a xmlnode list which I get it from web service];
    return "<root>"+xmln_list.InnerXml+"</root>";
}
```

*XSLT:*

[defined namespace **myclass** in xslt, which imports a method retunxml]

```
<xsl:for-each select="myclass:retunxml()/event" >
    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>                   
</xsl:for-each>
```

How to properly write xslt, so that it return me correctly titles of events defined in xml?

Comment: Your C# "function" has a return type of `string` even though it is returning a `XmlNode`.

Comment: thanks, an error. mistyped. corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the namespace import at the top of your XSL in order to use the .NET XSLT extension object (I can't remember the exact syntax), I think you actually need to change the C# code so it returns an `XPathNodeIterator` object.

There's an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx) which explains about XSLT parameters, but I think the table of types still applies to XSLT extension object methods. This might be of use. Basically, if you want XSL to iterate over something from a .NET method, you're going to have to return something richer than a string.